# How to get grep to output filename first and multiple line context next

Tags: bash, grep

I want the output of grep to be something like:

```
path/filename1-
line1
match
line3
--
path/filename2-
line1
match
line3
```

If I do a `grep -h -C 3 match file` I get close, but no filename. From the man page I don't see any other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ack does exactly that.

```
$ ack get -C3
unuse
7-
8-my $url = shift || die 'specify a URL';
9-
10:$mech->get( $url );
11-
12-my $text = $mech->content;
13-

whack
47-    Note that this script uses PPI and works only on perl
48-    scripts, modules, tests, etc. PPI takes a bit of time
49-    too, so if running this on an entire large repo, you
50:    may want to multitask or get some coffee.
51-
52-    By default, searches recursively for perl files in . and
53-    identifies the subroutine most likely to invoke confusion
```

Also, note that although it doesn't show here, the output is color-coded.  The filenames ("unuse" and "whack" in this example) are in green, the line numbers are in yellow, and the matching strings are inverse yellow.

ack is a search tool like grep that is specifically geared to programmers.  It is available at http://betterthangrep.com, and many *nix distributions have it as a package.  Debian-derived packages package ack as "ack-grep".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that directly with grep.  You could perhaps write a wrapper, maybe with sed that would do it.  If you use the `-Z` flag then grep will separate the filename from the matched part (so also use `-H` to get the filename).  Then perhaps keep track of the current filename, and when it changes print it out, then a newline, but otherwise just drop it from the front of the matched lines.  Come to think of it, perl would also work